# iOS: Require Retina Display in plist

Tags: ios, plist, retina-display

This is an odd request, but I would like to be able to require devices to have a retina display in order to build an application. Is there a key and value I can add to my plist to add that build requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if there id a front camera, and set it in the info.plist UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key.

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>front-facing-camera</string>
</array>
```

look here for more details:
[iPhoneOSKeys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html)

BTW
That will work for iPhone only.

Comment: but iPad 2 has front facing camera and no retina display

Comment: But I would appreciate it still working on the iPad 3 for now, since it does have iPad capabilities, but it doesn't have non-retina assets.